# How to create a class which will periodically update its variables based on the file content

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am experimenting with writing a small REST API with Flask. Since I do not want to introduce a database at the moment, I plan to store all information required by clients in memory.
Right now a cron job collects data from the web, analyses it and writes the results to a file. The task of the REST API is to provide this data partially(based on the incoming parameters) to the clients.
Here is an example of code, that in my opinion will do the job:

```
class DataAnalyzer:
    TYPE_DAY = 'day'
    TYPE_WEEK = 'week'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__daily_stats__ = []
        self.__weekly_stats__ = []

    def __load_stats__(self, daily_file, weekly_file, interval):
        while True:
            self.__daily_stats__ = [line.strip() for line in open(daily_file, 'r').readlines()]
            self.__weekly_stats__ = [line.strip() for line in open(weekly_file, 'r').readlines()]

            time.sleep(interval)

    def start(self, daily_file, weekly_file, interval):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.__load_stats__, args=(daily_file, weekly_file, interval))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def get_stats(self, stats_type, skip, count):
        if stats_type == self.TYPE_WEEK:
            data_to_filter = self.__weekly_stats__
        elif stats_type == self.TYPE_DAY:
            data_to_filter = self.__daily_stats__
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown type of statistics: '" + stats_type + "'")

        result_list = itertools.islice(data_to_filter, skip, (skip + count))

        return list(result_list)
```

Since my python experience is very low, I am curious how it should be done for the real world. How thread safety should be achieved in this case?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What will be when file will be modified while you are reading it?

Comment: @Jimilian Actually I would like to avoid this situation. Is it possible to somehow lock on the file?

Comment: @Zzokk, if your operational system like UNIX, you can use https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it. [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) helps you :)
If you want really multithread app, you should use [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

> Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) is a mechanism used in computer language
>   interpreters to synchronize the execution of threads so that only one
>   thread can execute at a time. An interpreter which uses GIL will
>   always allow exactly one thread to execute at a time, even if run on a
>   multi-core processor.

Your threads will be executed one after another. Not at same time. So, your `data_to_filter` will be consistent at any time.
And I think you can change

```
result_list = itertools.islice(data_to_filter, skip, (skip + count))
return list(result_list)
```

to

```
return data_to_filter[skip, skip+count]
```

Comment: Could you you give more details? As I see it **load_stats()** will be called in the one thread and **get_stats()** in another. Nevertheless both of them modify/access **daily_stats** and **weekly_stats**. How does GIL guarantees that stats won't be modified while **get_stats()** accesses it?

Comment: Assignment is atomic operation. When `load_stats()` are executing, `[ ... ]` generates **new list**. After that you assign this list to variable `_stats_`. It happens in one thread.
In other thread you just made a copy of your stats. Copy operations are atomic too.
While `get_stats()` are working, other thread can't work.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you won't be updating and fetching data at the same time You can use Lock.

Good explanation and examples of locking with python You can find here:
http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/

Comment: Author are using threading module. That's why it's impossible to update and fetch data at the same time. Daily and weekly stats are separated and not syncronized. This example is no need in locks.

Comment: That's true but the question is how to achived thread safety in general.

Comment: How does threading module guarantees that data is not modified and updated at the same time?